# D3 Updating x axis ticks throws error "translate(NaN,0)"

Tags: d3.js

I have a function in CoffeeScript to update a line graph based on data passed into it:

```
update_graph = (response_array) ->
  labels = window.legendLabels
  margin =
    top: 35
    right: 20
    bottom: 20
    left: 40

  width = $('#response_container').width() - margin.left - margin.right
  height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom

  svg = d3.select(".d3-graph svg")


  lines = color.domain().map((name) ->
    name: name
    values: response_array.filter((response) -> labels[response.index] == name).map((d) ->
      value: d.value
      created_at: formatDate(d.created_at)
    )
  )

  x = d3.time.scale().domain(d3.extent(response_array, (d) -> new Date(formatDate(d.created_at)))).range([0, width])
  y = d3.scale.linear().domain([-5, 5]).range([height, 0])

  xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom")
  svg.selectAll("g.x.axis").call(xAxis)
```

It seems like right where I call

```
  xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom")
  svg.selectAll("g.x.axis").call(xAxis)
```

I sometimes get the following error in my JS console:

`Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="translate(NaN,0)"`

I tried only setting the `extent` if there was an element in `d` but that didn't do the trick. Has anyone seen this before and fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out. I believe the problem was trying to set/update the x axis based on new values when the x axis domain wasn't set (or it was set to NaN values). So setting the x axis domain with default values before the graph updates seems to have fixed it. Something like:

```
if response_array.length > 0
  x = d3.time.scale().domain(d3.extent(response_array, (d) -> new Date(formatDate(d.created_at)))).range([0, width])
else
  dateNow = new Date()
  date30MinutesFromNow = new Date().getTime() + (10 * 60000)
  x = d3.time.scale().domain([dateNow, date30MinutesFromNow]).range([0, width])
```